# Text decoration none not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have text decoration:none for the spans listed under anchor tag. When other styles are working, this particular style is not working. Am I missing something ?

```css
a * {
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li><a href="">Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, <dolphia>consectetur</dolphia> adipiscing elit.</a>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li><a href=""><span>Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur</span> adipiscing elit.</a>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li><a href=""><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing

 elit.</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get an effect__like__this__?

Comment: @willoller: I am just trying to NOT have the words inside span tag underlined.

Comment: Xufox, LGSon, I checked that. It's not what I am asking.

Comment: It is a duplicate, not of your question but of the answer in that link, which is the exact same solution as in this answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
a *{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Hello<span>world!</span></a>
```

Comment: You should know by now, to flag a dupe question and not answer it.